# knn density estimation R

Tags: r, nearest-neighbor

Is there any function/package to perform k-Nearest Neighbor based density estimation in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

class package: function knn

ipred package: function ipredknn

[This search on Baron's Site](http://search.r-project.org/cgi-bin/namazu.cgi?query=%22k%20nearest%20neighbor%22&max=100&result=normal&sort=score&idxname=functions) brings up 29 hits.

And the [Multivariate Task View](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/views/Multivariate.html) has two sections on classification, and has links to a few packages that do knn and related tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it, but the the [kknn](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kknn/index.html) package might help.

You might also look at [class](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/class/index.html) and [knncat](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/knncat/index.html) for classification using k-nearest neighbor functions.