# Volume estimation with K_NN using R

Tags: r, kernel-density, probability-density

I need to find the density of each point within a data set using k-NN density estimation algorithm. I understand the basic approach used for calculation as shown in the screenshot below. [Complete slides at [link]](http://courses.cs.tamu.edu/rgutier/cs790_w02/l9.pdf)
[image]

I want to know is there any library within R which provides functions to calculate K-NN density estimation. Although there are some relevant questions on the same topic on stackoverflow, but none of them is properly answered.

Note: I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840983/knn-density-estimation-r) relevant, but again the answers do not work.

Comment: not answered? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840983/knn-density-estimation-r

Comment: @hrbrmstr, I agree with you. But the answers do not provide what I am asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I did not find any R package which calculates density at a point. But, I followed these steps to calculate density at each point:

1. I create a distance matrix for all the given points on plot (scatter-plot). Therefore for N points, I have *N x N* distance matrix, where each element (i, j) represents the Eucledian distance between *ith* and *jth* point.
2. Now using distance matrix, For each point I sorted out (in increasing order) the distances with respect to other points. Therefore, now if I want the distance of *kth* neighbor, I simply choose the *kth* sorted distance.
3. With *Kth* neighbor distance,I get the radius of circle. Therefore now I can substitute the radius value in the formula shown in the above picture. With this I am able to calculate density at a point.

Note: In R, neighbors are sorted according to distance using *order( )* function